# Spring @Scheduled stops running when system time set back

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have Spring Boot based cron job running:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "30 * * * * *}")
// @Scheduled(initialDelay = -1, fixedDelay = 60000)
public void cronCheck()
{
    instance.refreshStatus();
    if (instance.status.isVerified() && !instance.status.isExpired())
    {
        instance.updateCheckTime();
    }
}
```

Most of the cases, it's running perfect. But when I changed the system time back , for example one month, it would run one single time and never run again. However, if I change system back forward, it would run as scheduled.
Anyone has any idea why this is happening and maybe a solution?
Highly appreciate it!

Comment: The task never executes or the code in the if block never executes?

Comment: Did you change the time on runtime?

Comment: Hi Alan, the method is not invoked again. ignore the if block, it's just internal logic.